# Using Excel Macros in both XLS and XLSX

Tags: excel, vba

How can i use the same macro in both the XLS and XLSX formats?

Is there anyhthing to be added in the XLSX format. i have written a small macro in XLSX (it has last column XFD) i want to use it in the XLS (it has last column as IV) .Is there anything to be changed?

This question is not about converting the file formats.

Comment: you need to save file in macro enabled format which is `XLSM`. Files with `XLSX` extension will delete all the macros which you place in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLSX provides a broader set of formulas and also VBA functionality. Additionally, [XLSX expands the row/column restriction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx) that exists before Excel 2007 (from 256 columns to 16,384).

If your macros are written using up to column 16,384 (XFD), you're going to have to perform the calculations in chunks to make them fit within the 256 column (IV) restriction of Excel 2003. If you're using variables and not writing everything to a sheet, then there should be no problem (barring running out of memory).

Without more detail, it's difficult to tell whether you're using a set of functions from Excel 2007 that may not be supported in Excel 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Which format was it written first? normally it should work in both formats of excel. As you are referring to last cell of both formats, it seems to have a code level issue than a version lavel.